# What does the following notation mean?

Tags: probability, notation

Very simple question here. I cannot seem to find anywhere online what this notation means in regards to probability. The notation I am referring to is the definition of the function $g(x)$, specifically the symbol that looks like roman numeral $2$.[image]

Comment: I don't know, but I would guess that $\Bbb{I}_{a \le x \le b}$ is the indicator function on $[a, b]$ (i.e. the set $\{x \in \Bbb{R} : a \le x \le b\}$). That is, $\Bbb{I}_{a \le x \le b}(x) = 1$ if $a \le x \le b$ and $\Bbb{I}_{a \le x \le b}(x) = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: That  $\Bbb I$ thing is not a Roman numeral, it is a capital letter I, in the same fancy style as the $\Bbb P$ at the beginning of the statement.

Comment: The notation $\mathbb{I}_{\{a\le x \le b\}}$ represents the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function), so $g(x) = 1$ if $a \le x \le b$, and $g(x) = 0$ otherwise. Then, $E[g(X)] = 0\cdot P[g(x) = 0] + 1\cdot P[g(x) = 1]$.

Answer (score 0):

1. The probability that the random variable $X$ lies between $a$ and $b$, inclusive.
2. The expected value of the indicator function that $x$ is between $a$ and $b$, inclusive.

The first has a value between $0$ and $1$, inclusive.